# How to stack/z-position multiple UIElements (uilabel, uiimageview, etc) on top of each other?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel, uielement

I've got several UI elements on my screen (programmatically) and am in need of an efficient way to give each subview a z-index setting, so I can stack certain elements over others.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plain `-addSubview:` method will add the new view on top of its siblings.

There are also a bunch of methods like `bringSubviewToFront:`, `insertSubview:belowSubview:`, etc. that you can use to manipulate the ordering, listed under "Managing the View Hierarchy" in the [UIView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW46)